# folder "ea-php55" deleted, now session doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

recently a huge size increase happend in a folder in cPanel host in this address:

```
.cagefs/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php55
```

it was about 700MB size. I couldn't even open this folder to see all files. so I deleted the entire folder and recreated it. I also set Permissions to 0700 (like it was before).

now session doesn't work. I can't even login to my website's admin panel. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Before it could have been with permission 0700 but the owner should be different - something like `http` or `www`. In case you can't change its owner to the proper one, you could change the permissions to 0777. Not the best solution, because it security risky, but it will work for a start.

Comment: See this: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/475  See if this path exist and is it OK with permissions and owners.

Comment: it didn't help. there is no php.ini file anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days finally solved the problem. I created a folder named "session" near public_html.

```
/public_html
/session
```

and added one line of php code to change the "session save path" to that folder :

```
ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../session'));
```

now session is working. I don't think this is a perfect way but at least it's working now.

#### if you see this and have a better way please write your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my similar problem by setting the session path to:

```
/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php55
```

instead of this (even if I use php 5.4):

```
/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php54
```

So in your case it should work with this:

```
/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56
```

instead of

```
/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php55
```

even if you use php 5.5 and assuming you have php 5.6 installed.