# Can I safely delete the sessions in cagefs/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-phpxx (xx being the version) in cpanel?

Tags: php, session

Can I safely delete the sessions in cagefs/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-phpxx (xx being the version) in cpanel?

I have over 1 gb of space occupied with them and they are 3-4 months old.

Comment: Hey, I think you should better ask server-management related questions on http://serverfault.com/about

Comment: Thank you. Well, my host provider deleted them:)) and I got notices after that. I restored the whole folder ea-php54 but the warnings are still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that these sessions files can be removed (at least I tried for php 7.0 via ftp and did not receive any notification/warning about it).

The problem with the 5.4 was that the folder was deleted and recreated...

like in this link [folder "ea-php55" deleted, now session doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075279/folder-ea-php55-deleted-now-session-doesnt-work)

I resolved that by setting the session path to /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php55 instead of /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php54 and using still php 5.4

Answer (score 1):

You can add this command end of session.pm on this directory '/usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/config/session.pm'

```
package Cpanel::Config::Session; 
our $SESSION_EXPIRE_TIME = ( 60 * 60 * 24);
```

> Clear all sission older 24 horse

This command clear all session in to 
'/usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Session/* '

[REF](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-does-cpanel-remove-session-expired-files.613587/)

Comment: Thank you @Hamed, I just added an answer to improve yours.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (with inodes saturation) and deleted the files without problems.

According to the suggestion by the Administrator of the cPanel forum referenced by @Hamed, I made a small script to be used in a cronjob. Hope this can help others (use with care at your own risk):

```
#!/bin/bash

session_dir="/var/cpanel/php/sessions"

touch --date "$(date -d '30 days ago' +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" $session_dir/older_than_this

find $session_dir -type f -not -newer $session_dir/older_than_this -delete
```

In this case the script deletes all session files older than 30 days.